# Common Decimal Format

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting, decimalformat

Is it possible to set a common decimal format for a variable?
ie: I want to set decimal precision for all variable to 2 decimal, Is there a common configuration that handles this?

Comment: Java doesn't have decimals, only floats.

Comment: You can [format your output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). However you cannot really tell Java to work with only two places after comma under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

No, a variable (ie. of type `double`) does not carry its own instance of `DecimalFormat`.

If you want to Write out values with in a specific format, the easiest way is not to use `DecimalFormat` directly, but rather use the `format()` methods of the [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) or [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) classes:

```
double x = 1.234;
System.out.format("x = %.02f%n", x); // prints "x = 1.23"
```

Here `%.02f` formats the argument to 2 decimal places, and `%n` is the line end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about representing them as string you can check out :

[Java DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)